# How to inspect Ember.js objects in the console?

Tags: ember.js

Is there any way to get at what an Ember.js object really contains in the JavaScript console. If you do `console.log(this)`, you will get almost the same data structure for almost any object, something like this:

[image: console.log of an Ember.js controller]

That's not super helpful, and it gives you no idea what attributes are actually set on the object.

So far, the only way I've found to debug is to try and `console.log(this.get('whatever'))` for any conceivable name, but it's hard to guess what's available.

Is there any way to dig deeper into the object's data?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Ember provides several methods to help debug an object from console:

**[Object.toString](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.CoreObject.html#method_toString)** prints identity of any ember object

```
App.Person = Em.Object.extend()
person = App.Person.create()
person.toString() 
//=> "<App.Person:ember1024>"
```

**[Ember.inspect](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html#method_inspect)** converts the object into a useful string description

```
var object = Ember.Object.create({
  firstName: 'Hansi',
  lastName: 'Hinterseer',
  age: 58
});
console.log( Ember.inspect(object) );
// {__ember1331067974108_meta: [object Object] , firstName: Hansi , lastName: Hinterseer , age: 58}
```

**[Ember.keys](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.html#method_keys)** returns all of the keys defined on an object or hash

```
console.log(Ember.keys(this));
```

Comment: Thanks, that makes it a bit easier to see what's going on under the covers :)

Comment: "Hansi Hinterseer" LOL

Comment: Note that Ember.inspect is gone in Ember 3.x (maybe 2.x?) so you have to do: import { getProperties } from '@ember/object'; THEN use getProperties(obj) to get a JS object that you can print to console

Answer (score 6):

There is also the `App.__container__` object which, if you know what name your objects are registered to the ember app with, will allow you to grab any object you need while debugging from any environment.

A couple of examples are

```
App.__container__.lookup('store:main') # Gets the store
App.__container__.lookup('controller:blog') # Gets the blog controller
```

Answer (score 1):

[ember-chrome-devtools](https://github.com/dwickern/ember-chrome-devtools) is a nice way to solve this problem now...

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to inspect an Ember Data record, you can call the [serialize](https://api.emberjs.com/ember-data/3.10/classes/DS.Serializer/methods/serialize?anchor=serialize) method on it from your console, this will give you the object as your external data source expects.