# Accessing ArrayController elements using needs

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I've got the following 2 controllers:

**controllers/student/index.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    hasDebt: function(){
        var totalCredit = this.get('totalCredit');
        var totalCreditSpent = this.get('totalCreditSpent');

        if (totalCreditSpent > totalCredit) 
        {
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }.property('payments.@each', 'lessons.@each'),
});
```

**controllers/students.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    itemController: 'student/index',
    sortProperties: ['fullName'],
    sortAscending: true,

    debts: function(){
        var allDebts = [];
        var totalDebts = 0;

        this.forEach(function(student){
            if (student.get('hasDebt'))
            {
                allDebts.push({
                    name: student.get('fullName'), 
                    amount: student.get('availableCredit')
                });

                totalDebts += student.get('availableCredit');
            }
        });

        return {'all': allDebts, 'total': totalDebts};
    }.property('this.@each.payments', 'this.@each.lessons'),
});
```

And everything is working as expected. I'm able to access the `hasDebt` property of each element through the `itemController`.

Now I'd like to show the debts in a dashboard in the IndexRoute, so I've created the following additional controller, hoping to be able to access the `StudentsController` by using needs:

**controllers/index.js**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: ['students'],

    debts: function(){
        var debts = [];

        console.log( this.get('controllers.students.debts') );

        this.get('controllers.students').forEach(function(student){
            console.log('student');
        });

        return debts;
    }.property(''),
});
```

I seem unable to access the `StudentsController` and any of its properties.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try controller instead of controllers.

Comment: @HasibMahmud I think controllers is correct as you can see from [this page](http://emberjs.com/guides/controllers/dependencies-between-controllers/)

Comment: Yeah I know but I faced a prob yesterday where I used `needs` & smthing like `Ember.computed.alias('controllers.posts.id')`. That didn't work & I got value of id undefined. When I tried `controller.posts.id`, I got the value. I don't know why it worked. So I was just suggesting to give it a try. Besides, I guess you are using Ember inspector. So through it you can easily find out if you are actually accessing the `StudentsController` or not.

Comment: @HasibMahmud Ok I understand, btw I tried with `students: Ember.computed.alias('controllers.students')` but it returns `undefined`

Comment: @HasibMahmud sorry I meant `Ember.computed.alias('controller.students')`

Comment: Ok, then try using `Ember.ObjectController` or `Ember.ArrayController` instead of `Ember.Controller` in **controllers/index.js**.

Comment: @HasibMahmud Same, still `undefined` with both

Answer (score 0):

I believe that a computed property must observe a property in order to ever be populated. In your example:

**controllers/index.js**

```
export default Ember.Controller.extend({
  needs: ['students'],
  students: Em.computed.alias('controllers.students'),
  debts: function() {
    ...
  }.property('students.debts')
});
```

In this example I also made it a little easier to use Students by providing a [Computed Alias](http://emberjs.com/api/#method_computed_alias) mapped to `students` in the controller.

### Debugging

It's also very handy to use the browser's console when debugging. Try running something like the following and see what comes back.

```
App.__container__.lookup('controller:index').get('students')
```

This assumes your application exists under the **App** namespace.

Comment: I've tried with `.property('students.debts')` and the `students` alias but it seems that the students controller cannot be accessed. If I do `console.log(this.get('students'))` I get the following: `[_super: function, nextObject: function, firstObject: undefined, lastObject: undefined, contains: function…] `. I've no Idea on how to export App to the global namespace using ember-cli...

Comment: This answer provides some more useful functions for debugging. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18247026/876180